# One Touchable Opacity for Play and Pause

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-sound

I want to use one TouchableOpacity for Play and Pause.

I am Using Audio from Firebase Server and react-native-sound to Play and Pause the Audio.
Here is My Code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        isPlaying: true
    }
}
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress= {() => { 
        const { isPlaying } = this.state;
        var sound = new Sound(`${item.sound}`, null, (error)=> {
            if (isPlaying == false) {
                sound.play();
                this.setState({isPlaying:!isPlaying})
                console.warn("Played");

            } else if(isPlaying == true){
                sound.pause();
                this.setState({isPlaying:!isPlaying})
                console.warn("Paused");
            }
        })
    }
}
key={i}>Play</TouchableOpacity>
```

I am Able to Play the Sound but not able Pause.

I am New to react-native. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    isPlaying: false
  }
  this.sound = new Sound();
}

startPlaying = () => {
  this.sound.play();
  this.setState({ isPlaying: true });
  console.warn("Now playing");
}

stopPlaying = () => {
  this.sound.pause();
  this.setState({ isPlaying: false })
  console.warn("Now paused");
}

onPlay(item) {
  const { isPlaying } = this.state;
  if(!isPlaying) {
    this.sound = new Sound(`${item.sound}`, null, this.startPlaying);
  } else {
    this.stopPlaying();
  }
}

<TouchableOpacity
   onPress={() => this.onPlay(item)}
   key={I}
>
   Play
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: this.sound = new Sound(); throws error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating new `Sound` instance on every Press, so when you call `sound.pause()` you are calling it on another `Sound` instance.

In your constructor or somewhere where you have access to `item.sound`, instantiate the Sound:

```
this.sound = new Sound(item.sound)
```

Your onPress callback should look like this:

```
    onPress= {() => {
     if(isPlaying) {
      this.sound.pause()
     } else {
      this.sound.play() 
    }
  }}
```